# when is an estimator consistent?

Tags: estimation, mixture-distribution, consistency

Say there are parameters $\theta$ such that $\theta_i > 0$ and $\sum_i \theta_i = 1$ and a model such as $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i p_i(x)$ where $p_i(x)$ are fixed and defined over a domain of random variable $X$. Say $X$ is a random variable which is a categorical variable.

Now, say we partition $x$ into equivalence classes, such that we have a new random variable $Y$ which is a more coarse version of $X$. This means that $Y = f(X)$ and $f$ maps several values of $X$ to the same value of $Y$.

Under what condition a consistent estimator for $\theta$ under the $Y$ model will be a consistent estimator for $\theta$ under the $X$ model? (By the $Y$ model I am referring to $p(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i p_i(y)$.) I have a feeling this largely depends on Rao-Blackwell, but not sure exactly how to apply it here.

Clearly there are cases where consistency is hopeless from the $Y$, for example, if $f$ maps all values of $X$ to just a single value. But say it is at the very least partitioning the space into two values? Can Rao-Blackwell help here? If it won't show consistency, what would it show?

EDIT: What would be a way to turn a consistent estimator under the $Y$ model to a consistent estimator for the $X$ model? Or at least a better estimator?

EDIT / refinement: Say we have multiple functions, $f_1$, $f_2$, etc and for each one of them there is a $f(Y_j)$ model. What would be assumptions on $f_j$ and a way to get a consistent estimator from $f(Y_j)$ for the $p(X)$ model?